# Are culture/location specific riddles allowed?

Tags: discussion, scope

I have a riddle I want to ask. However, it is culture/location specific, and the answer involves a language of that culture (even though the question is in English). To mention the language would give away the answer, but people who don't speak it wouldn't have a hope of getting it. (Worse still it's not a commonly used language like French/Spanish)

Is this type of riddle OK for this site, and is it enough to just mention the culture?